# How to Use Ternary Operator in Python

Tags: python

I have this method:

```
def get_compression_settings(self, media_type=None):
        return self.transmit('GET', 'compression?mediatypeid={0}'.format(media_type))
```

Is there a way I can check if media_type == None and only append mediatypeid={0} if it is ~=None in a single line using a ternary operator?

I know I could do the following, but it would nicer if my method could just be a single return:

```
def get_compression_settings(self, media_type=None):
        endpoint = 'compression?mediatypeid={0}'.format(media_type) if media_type is not None else 'compression'
        return self.transmit('GET', endpoint)
```

Comment: You could have a one-line method body, but I think you should instead prefer a readable method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a single line return, as:

```
return self.transmit('GET', 'compression?mediatypeid={0}'.format(media_type)
                             if media_type is not None else 'compression')
```

I split it onto multiple lines to improve readability, but that is not necessary for it to work. (Note that this required changing `if media_type not none` in your example to `if media_type is not None`).

Comment: I fixed the none issue. Thanks!

Comment: Did this answer your question about fitting it on one line?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
return self.transmit('GET', 'compression?mediatypeid={0}'.format(media_type) if media_type is not None else 'compression')
```

Comment: Also don't forget to change `none` to `None` (then I'll happily remove my downvote)